# Ubuntu 19.04 lm-sensors functions only partially

Tags: 19.04, lm-sensors

After upgrading from Ubuntu 18.10 to Ubuntu 19.04 (Disco Dingo) the command `/usr/bin/sensors -A` no longer shows the fan information. Before upgrate I get this kind of information:

```
fan1:                      334 RPM  (min =    0 RPM)
fan2:                      864 RPM  (min =    0 RPM)
fan6:                     1076 RPM  (min =    0 RPM)
SYSTIN:                    +23.0°C  (high = +98.0°C, hyst = +95.0°C)  sensor = thermistor
CPUTIN:                    +27.5°C  (high = +80.0°C, hyst = +75.0°C)  sensor = thermistor
AUXTIN0:                   +23.5°C    sensor = thermistor
AUXTIN2:                   +23.0°C    sensor = thermistor
AUXTIN3:                   +97.0°C    sensor = thermistor
PECI Agent 0:              +30.0°C  (high = +98.0°C, hyst = +95.0°C)
PECI Agent 0 Calibration:  +27.0°C  
Core 0:        +27.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 1:        +33.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 2:        +30.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 3:        +29.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
```

while after upgrade I get only this:

```
asus-isa-0000
cpu_fan:        0 RPM

acpitz-acpi-0
temp1:        +27.8°C  (crit = +119.0°C)

coretemp-isa-0000
Package id 0:  +34.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 0:        +32.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 1:        +34.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 2:        +33.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 3:        +32.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
```

I have the modules *coretemp* and *nct6775* already declared into */etc/modules* (same as for Ubuntu 18.10) and I also run `sudo sensors-detect` which also recommends those modules.

I have an [Asus H370-I](https://www.asus.com/Motherboards/ROG-STRIX-H370-I-GAMING/) motherboard with an [i3-8300 Intel](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/129942/intel-core-i3-8300-processor-8m-cache-3-70-ghz.html) CPU.

What is the problem and how should I solve it?

Answer (score 1):

Editing `/etc/default/grub` and adding `acpi_enforce_resources=lax` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` might solve your problem.

So it looks something like this...

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_enforce_resources=lax"
```

I have read though that adding this may cause instability.